# two loops based on condition

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to get post to loop based on conditions

```
If (book_status === "published" || !empty($url)) {
while (have_posts()) : ?>

html code...

elseif (book_status !== "published" && || empty($url){
while (have_posts()) : ?>
html code alternative.
```

essentially trying to create two grids. One that shows the published work and one that shows the unpublished work. However, no matter where I put the if statement, I cannot seem to make it work with the loop. I reverted it back to testing if it works with the buttons. It does.

````
    
    <!-- .entry-header -->
     <?php
$url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_url', true ); 
$book_status = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_book_published', true );
?>
    <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail()  ) : ?>
        <figure class="entry-thumbnail">
        <caption><h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></caption>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">                
                <?php if ( is_home() && $blog_sidebar_position == 'content-fullwidth' ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail('type-small');
                } elseif ( ( is_archive() || is_search() ) && $archive_sidebar_position == 'content-fullwidth') {
                    the_post_thumbnail('type-small');
                } else {
                    the_post_thumbnail('type-small');
                }   
                ?>
            </a>
        </figure><div class="container works-buttons">
<?php if( !empty( $url ) && $book_status == "published"){
echo '<button class="amazon fa fa-amazon" id="amazon" type="button"><a class="amazon-link" href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">Buy</a></button>'; ?>
<button type="button" class="fa type22 fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"><a href="/shop">Signed</a></button> 
<button type="button" class="fa type22 "><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">About</a></button>
<?php
 } elseif ( !empty( $url ) && $book_status !== "published"){
echo '<button class="amazon fa fa-amazon" id="amazon" type="button"><a class="amazon-link" href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">Buy</a></button>'; ?>
<button type="button" class="fa type22 fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"><a href="/shop">Signed</a></button> 
<button type="button" class="fa type22 "><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">About</a></button>

<?php } else{ ?>
<button type="button" class="fa type22 fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"><a href="/shop">Get Updates</a></button> 
<button type="button" class="fa type22 "><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">About</a></button>
<?php }

 ?>

</div>
<?php
 endif; ?>
</article>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </section>```
````

Comment: Have you tried resetting the main WP_Query loop by calling [rewind_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/rewind_posts/) after your have_posts() loops?

Comment: nope! Although at the minute, I can't get the loops to work with just the if statement. I didn't get as far as trying elseif yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're inside the [main post loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) already when you do

```
while (have_posts()) {
   ...
   the_post();
}
```

your code will use up all the posts in the main loop.

If you want to look at other posts based on the current post in your main loop, you need to use a different [WP_Query object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#usage).  Something like this.

```php
$myQuery = new WP_Query( appropriate_query_args );
if ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) {
        $myQuery->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```